# Google Sheets - How to create a dropdown filter to hide columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I must have been Googling and trialing/erroring in scripting for 4-5 hours now, I'm stuck in a (frustrating) loop.

I'm trying to create a drop-down filter in A1 which lists all of the values in C1:ZZZ1, and selecting one of the values hides all columns C1:ZZZ1 except the columns that fall under the selected value's merged cell.

Example from the below screenshot:
In A1 would show a drop-down pulled dynamically, which lists "Joe Adams", "Eagle Nest", and "Sabrina". If I select "Eagle Nest" in the A1 drop-down, all I would see is Column A, Column B, and Columns F, G, and H (since Eagle Nest is merged with these 3 columns). The rest of the columns would be hidden. Then, upon clearing the filter (drop-down), all columns would be visible. Is something like this possible??

[image]

Comment: Absolutely, columns can be programmatically hidden and unhidden. See my code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182540/9337071 . [Data Validation in a cell can also be programmatically altered.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks! I'm not sure I understand but 25% of that reference, but I'll take a deeper dive and try to figure things out

Answer (score 0):

INDEX/OFFSET is another option. In another sheet, (say Sheet2!A1): Create a drop down for Sheet1!1:1,

A2:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!1:1,0)-1,90,3))
```

Syntax:

```
OFFSET(cell_reference,‎ offset_rows,‎ offset_columns,‎ [height],‎ [width])
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm really looking for a solution that keeps the drop-down on the sheet itself, not creating a separate sheet