# GSheets: Script Hide/Unhide columns based on value: How to run this script to specific sheets only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with this working  script to hide columns based on values, I'd like to run the script to specific sheets (A,B,C,D,E) for example

Spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IDeRrQkJLohGtPf8sEgnG-jUGx2IrXx5VhE-L-GkjQk/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function onOpen() {
var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('A');
b.showColumns(1, b.getMaxColumns());
b.getRange('4:4')
    .getValues()[0]
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r && r == 'x') b.hideColumns(i + 1)
    });
```

}

It does what I'm looking for in Sheet A only, (but I don't know if it is the best method to achieve it).

Situation:

I have the same template in all sheets with multiple ranges of weeks:

Week 1:  J:AB

Week 2:  AC:AU

Week 3:  AV:BN

Week 4:  BO:CG

Week 5:  CH:CZ

Week 6:  DA:DS

Week 7:  DT:EL

Helper columns: EM:ET  which should be always be hidden

The idea basically is to be able to run a script in all sheets that would enable me to hide a specific week or columns.

My initial idea was to have a sheet called "Tracker" containing empty cells or x. I would hide line 4 in A,B,C,D,E which would contain the values in Tracker. Upon opening the sheets A,B,etc... users will be able to see only the columns not containing x in the Tracker Sheet.

How would I run this script (or another one with a better approach) to the specific sheets mentioned above to be able to control which week or columns should be visible or not?

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Call it `onOpen(e)` and call your loop from `e.source.getSheets().forEach`, check that the sheet name is in an array of desired sheets, and if so, call your hiding routine.

Comment: An `onEdit` function should absolutely never reference `active____`. Why? because the user is free to continue doing things while the function is executing. Meaning the context of the active objects is free to change. The input [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) (the parameter, for example `e`, passed to the function) contains all the information and references you need.

Comment: Calling `e.source.getSheets()` returns an array of the sheets of the source workbook. Calling `.forEach` from said array would then run your function on every sheet of the source workbook. If you want to make a different function, one which is called from a menu, consider reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208357/google-sheets-hiding-columns-based-on-date-in-row-1/49182540

Comment: Thank you for your indications, I don't want to call it from a menu as I've got many folders containing the same spreadsheets. My idea was to use IMPORTRANGE in each one of them to import values from a Master Sheet and then the script would run automatically. But with my knowledge I won't be able to achieve anything at the moment. So I would really appreciate your help if I can achieve this.