# Loop through URLs in range of cells and hide their columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn Google Apps Scripts for use with Google Spreadsheets.

I have a list of URls (not sure if I can just the Sheet Ids?) for Google Sheets in one column and I want to write a script that opens the files, hides a specific column and then loops onto the next Sheet.

I've found this script which I'm trying to use as a start point but I just get the error 'Missing variable name. (line 8, file "Code")'

```
function getTitles() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var urls = sheet.getRange("G3:G").getValues();
  var titleList = [], newValues = [],
      response, doc, title;

  for (var row = 0, var len = urls.length; row < len; row++) {
    if (urls[row] != '') {
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[row]);
      doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(),true);
      title = doc.html.head.title.getText();
      newValues.push([title]);  
      titleList.push(title);  
      Logger.log(title);
    } else newValues.push([]);
  }

  Logger.log('newValues ' + newValues);
  Logger.log('titleList ' + titleList);

  // SET NEW COLUMN VALUES ALL AT ONCE!
  sheet.getRange("H3").offset(0, 0, newValues.length).setValues(newValues);
  return titleList; 
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When posting an error message that has a line number, identify that line on your posted code. As for hiding columns, a recent question shows how that can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49443535/9337071

Comment: You should also use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` to work directly with the desired spreadsheet - **if** you have appropriate access privileges to them.